# Running helloworld-rs from JBoss quickstarts in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to learn JAX-RS using [JBoss quickstarts](http://www.jboss.org/developer/quickstarts.html). 
When I deployed the application "helloworld-rs" through command-line, it ran successfully. Then I created a maven project in Eclipse, copied files from "helloworld-rs" at proper locations and it worked fine. Then I went ahead to add a form to the existing index.html file and something went wrong. Instead off deploying "jboss-as-helloworld-rs", Eclipse started deploying "jboss-as-helloworld-osgi" for some unknown reasons. Obviously, it produced error when I tried to access "localhost:8080/jboss-as-helloworld-rs/index.html"

So I created a new Maven project in Eclipse with following details:

`Group Id:org.jboss.as.quickstarts.rshelloworld`

```
Artifact Id: jboss-hello
```

I have also made changes in pom.xml as follows:

```
 <artifactId>jboss-hello</artifactId>
```

Still I am facing the same problem. I have made a copy of "helloworld-rs", made same changes in the pom.xml and deployed and ran it successfully through command-line using

`http://localhost:8080/jboss-hello/index.html`

Strangely, this very link does not work in eclipse!!!
 I have zeroed-in that there is some problem in deploying th app in Eclipse. Can anybody please help me solve this? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the 'jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments' folder, deleted all the deployed war files. Then in Eclipse, right-click on servers -> clean . Then, I started the JBoss server and everything went fine.